# Use 1 column as a header in a table with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP file that displays the results of a SQL query in a table. The table lists items in customer orders. A sample table is below:

```
select * from v_orders:
order_number    location    order_stage    item    quantity
1               Patio1      3              17      2
1               Patio1      3              35      1
1               Patio1      3              13      6
2               Patio3      1              17      4
2               Patio3      1              15      1
2               Patio3      1              16      5
```

Columns order_number, location and stage are pulled from a single row in another table, so they're always the same. I want my PHP script to make a new HTML table every time it encounters a new order number. order_number, location, and stage will make up the first row of each table, and item and quantity will make up all subsequent rows. When the script finds a new order number, it starts a new table. In addition, each table will have a button at the bottom to update the order.

Here's how I want the final output to appear.

```
Order: 1    Location: Patio1    Stage: 3
Item: 17    Qty: 2
Item: 35    Qty: 1
Item: 13    Qty: 6
(button)Update Order 1

Order: 2    Location: Patio3    Stage: 1
Item: 17    Qty: 4
Item: 15    Qty: 1
Item: 16    Qty: 5
```

Here's the PHP I've written. The variable $new_table holds the HTML to build these tables. The script uses a familiar while loop to iterate through each row. When the current row has an order_number field that different from the previous row, it adds a button and  to close off the previous table and adds  and headers to start a new table:

```
<?php
    include "../util.php";  //Includes the connect string $connect
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM v_orders WHERE waiter=$id AND order_stage <> 4 ORDER BY order_number");

//Placeholder to hold the current order in the row.
$current_order = 0;

//while loop to iterate through the query results
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    if($row['order_number'] != $current_order){ 

    //Add button to the previous table and close, then start a new table
    $new_table .= '
        <tr>
        <td><button onclick="update(\'enter_order.php?order= '.$current_number.' \')">Modify Order</button></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="padding:20px;border:5">
        <tr><th>Order Number: '.$row['order_number'].'</th><th>Location: '.$row['location'].'</th><th>Stage: '.$row['order_stage'].'</th></tr>';

    //Set the placeholder variable to the current order number.
    $current_number = $row['order_number'];
}

//Add item and quantity data. Note that this code runs with every iteration of $row
$new_table.='
    <tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td><td>'.$row['price'].'</td></tr>';
} //end while loop

//After the while loop, close the last table.
$new_table.= '
    <tr>
    <td><button onclick="update(\'enter_order.php?order='.$current_number.'\')">Modify Order</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>';

//Finally, echo the new_table variable to the browser. It should be properly formed HTML.
echo $new_table; ?>
```

This works great. I get a nice self-contained table for each order. Except it puts a "modify order" button above the first table. How can I strip that out? I tried using the ltrim command as such:

```
 $new_table = ltrim($new_table, '<tr>
        <td><button onclick="update(\'enter_order.php?order= '.$current_number.' \')">Modify Order</button></td>
        </tr>);
```

But the command got hopelessly confused by all the whitespace. Where you see a space or a tab, the ltrim command took out extra characters. I spent hours trying to remove all the white space and fit everything on one line. But that got me hopelessly confused because I got lost without any proper indentation.

Rather than fight with the ltrim command, I'd like to just change my whole algorithm. Is there some way I can add the right code to the end of each table (Move....) without sticking it all the way at the top of while loop?

Comment: There is a logic error. When the `while` loop through the first row the `if($row['order_number'] != $current_number)` is executed because `$current_number` is undefined at this stage. That's why you've got button above first table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above the loop, you set the value of $current_order, but it isn't used in the loop. That's fine. This code depends on $current_number being undefined during the first loop. Your algorithm isn't bad, it just needs code specific to the very first loop to make it work.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    if (!$current_number) {//first loop, $current_number doesn't exist yet

        $new_table .= '
        <table style="padding:20px;border:5">
        <tr><th>Order Number: '.$row['order_number'].'</th><th>Location:'.$row['location'].'</th><th>Stage: '. $row['order_stage'].'</th></tr>';
    }

    if(($row['order_number'] != $current_number) && ($current_number)){//won't fire on the first iteration

        //Add button to the previous table and close, then start a new table
        $new_table .= '
        <tr>
        <td><button onclick="update(\'enter_order.php?order= '.$current_number.' \')">Modify Order</button></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="padding:20px;border:5">
        <tr><th>Order Number: '.$row['order_number'].'</th><th>Location: '.$row['location'].'</th><th>Stage: '.
        $row['order_stage'].'</th></tr>';   
    }

    //Add item and quantity data. Note that this code runs with every iteration of $row
    $new_table.='<tr><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td><td>'.$row['price'].'</td></tr>';

    //Set the placeholder variable to the current order number. 
    $current_number = $row['order_number'];
} //end while loop
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I added &&($current_order != 0), just because I like to declare and initialize variables before I use them. Either way that worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should end the table and add the button only when you have the content in $new_table already.

```
if ($row['order_number'] != $current_number) { 
    if (strlen($new_table) > 0) {
        $new_table .= '
        <tr>
        <td><button onclick="update(\'enter_order.php?order= '.$current_number.' \')">Modify Order</button></td>
        </tr>
        </table>';
    }


    $new_table .= '     
    <table style="padding:20px;border:5">
    <tr><th>Order Number: '.$row['order_number'].'</th><th>Location: '.$row['location'].'</th><th>Stage: '.$row['order_stage'].'</th></tr>';

    //Set the placeholder variable to the current order number.
    $current_number = $row['order_number'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some tested code that does what you want.

It uses the 'read ahead' technique for the data rows. It simplifies the logic as you do things in the order the appear rather than trying to sort out what you did last.

This technique is to read a record before you start processing the data. 
Process the record.
Read the next record.

PHP 5.3.18 on windows XP (XAMPP)

The comments try and explain what is happening.

Sample output:

```
Order Number: 1 Location: Patio1    Stage: 3
17  2   21.00
35  1   22.22
13  6   23.00
Modify Order

Order Number: 2 Location: Patio3    Stage: 1
17  4   31.00
15  1   32.00
16  5   21.00
Modify Order



<?php


session_start();

//..
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'testmysql');

//    include "../util.php";  //Includes the connect string $connect
//    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM v_orders ORDER BY order_number");


// Although it is a little clumsy, the code for while loops
// is easier if you use the 'read ahead' technique of the row data
// this means that changes cause the current processing to stop

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

//while loop to iterate through all the orders...
while(isset($row['order_number'])) {

    //Set the placeholder variable to the current order number.
    $current_number = $row['order_number'];

    // Start a new table...
    echo '<table style="padding:20px;border:5">'
               .'<tr><th>Order Number: '.$row['order_number']
                    .'</th><th>Location: '.$row['location']
                    .'</th><th>Stage: '.$row['order_stage'].'</th></tr>';

    // write all the table rows for the current order
    while ($row['order_number'] == $current_number) {

      echo '<tr><td>'.$row['item'].'</td><td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td><td>'.$row['price'].'</td></tr>';


      // read next row -- may be for a different order
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    }

    // Add button to the  current table and close.
    echo '<tr><td><button onclick="update(\'enter_order.php?order= '.$current_number.' \')">Modify Order</button></td></tr></table>';


} // end of all the orders

?>
```

Comment: Genius idea. I knew I had to split the code inside the while loop into two parts: The "opening and closing the table" part, and the "adding rows to the table" part. I made the "adding rows" part of the normal flow of the table, and wrapped the "opening and closing" part in a branching statement. Your code almost takes an opposite approach: The "opening and closing" are part of the normal flow, and the "adding rows" part is in a nested loop. It achieves the same results, but it looks much nicer. Thanks for the advice.